# Do you know the name of this component?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on a project and I need a component similar to the one in the picture to select a date. I know this can be achieved using maybe adapters or something, but I don't want to redo something that already exists. Thank you.[image]

Comment: The question is asking what a component is called

Comment: Seems like a thing that you'll have to redo it because it hasn't been done

Answer (score 0):

The component is a Picker
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

I don't see a TimePicker with the format in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom View extending ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) and
You can Use material picker for these text view : 
https://github.com/KasualBusiness/MaterialNumberPicker

```
MaterialNumberPicker numberPicker1 = new MaterialNumberPicker.Builder(context)
                            .minValue(0)
                            .maxValue(59)
                            .defaultValue(defultValueMin)
                            .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                            .separatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                            .textColor(Color.BLACK)
                            .textSize(20)
                            .formatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
                                @Override
                                public String format(int value) {
                                    return String.format("%02d", value);
                                }
                            })
                            .enableFocusability(false)
                            .wrapSelectorWheel(true)
                            .build();
```

use formatter to format your text. 
add your custom view you can use everywhere you want like

then init layout inflators in your custom view

```
init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, this, true)
        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.item_View,
                    0, 0)
        }


<com.packagepath.yourcustomview 
             android:id="@+id/customview"
 .../>
```

customview.setValueListenrs in the activity or fragment to get the dates time and seconds.